# Update field from two tables as concatenated field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made a select statement that I am happy with.

```
SELECT 
PC.FIELD||T.FIELD
FROM 
TABLE1 T, TABLE2 PC
WHERE
T.PART_NO=PC.PART_NO
```

Now I am stuck with how to update a field in TABLE1 with the concatenation PC.FIELD||T.FIELD. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: use this select statement into update where condition

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 UPDATE table1 t
  set FIELD = (SELECT  
                  PC.FIELD||T.FIELD
                  FROM 
                    TABLE2 PC
                  WHERE
                  T.PART_NO=PC.PART_NO 
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

UPDATE t set FIELD = a.NewField
from TABLE1 t 
join (SELECT  T.PART_NO, PC.FIELD||T.FIELD as NewField
      FROM TABLE1 T, TABLE2 PC
      WHERE T.PART_NO = PC.PART_NO ) A
on t.PART_NO = a.PART_NO